# How can I edit the displayed survey information on a list form?

Tags: 2013

[image: This is what I am talking about.]

I already tried to edit the list form views but can't find anything.

Comment: This might be a survey list. What information do you want to edit?

Comment: I'd like to remove that table and write just a description with maybe an image.

Comment: Did you tried it? I have already tested the code given in my answer & it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below mentioned code to replace the table with your desired HTML content/text.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

var els = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-summarystandardbody'),
    i = els.length;

setTimeout(function () {
    while (i--) {
        var str = '<a href="http://www.com">item to replace</a>'; //it can be anything
var Obj = els[i]; //any element to be fully replaced
if(Obj.outerHTML) { //if outerHTML is supported
    Obj.outerHTML=str; ///it's simple replacement of whole element with contents of str var
}
else { //if outerHTML is not supported, there is a weird but crossbrowsered trick
    var tmpObj=document.createElement("div");
    tmpObj.innerHTML='<!--THIS DATA SHOULD BE REPLACED-->';
    ObjParent=Obj.parentNode; //Okey, element should be parented
    ObjParent.replaceChild(tmpObj,Obj); //here we placing our temporary data instead of our target, so we can find it then and replace it into whatever we want to replace to
    ObjParent.innerHTML=ObjParent.innerHTML.replace('<div><!--THIS DATA SHOULD BE REPLACED--></div>',str);
}
    }
}, 1500);

}
</script>
```

I have tried it using CEWP on the same page & it is working and replaces the table with "`<a href="http://www.com">item to replace</a>`" on button click. You can convert it to work on page load.

**Note:-**

The `getElementsByClassName("ms-summarystandardbody")` method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.

Comment: Works for me too Hardik :)

Comment: Happy to hear that it is working for you as well. :)

Comment: Do needful to answer buddy... :)

Comment: If it works for you than please mark it as correct so others can get benefit of it.

Comment: I think you forgot to accept as you already said that it is working for you.

Comment: If you are getting this message than its my humble request to you that please mark the answer as correct (Accept it as correct answer).

Comment: If you don't know how to do it than please check this link... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work